# Get range from table (inclusive)

Tags: perl

I want to print all lines that are within a specified range. The test code I have so far is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
my $start = "25823";
my $end = "35841";

while (<DATA>) {
    if ( /(\S+)?\t(\d+)?\t(\d+)?/ ) {
        my $feat = $1;
        my $datastart = $2;
        my $dataend = $3;
        if ( $datastart >= $start && $dataend <= $end ) { print }
    }
}

__DATA__
A       23594   24158 
W       25646   25978
X       26189   26770
Y       31694   33466
Z       34568   36125
B       37516   38912
```

but this only prints lines X and Y, which are within the range but in an exclusive form. However I would like to get all inclusive lines so that the output would be W, X, Y and Z. How can that be accomplished?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, but 25823 is less than 25978, that's why I would like to have inclusive ranges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want overlapping ranges (instead of just total inclusion), you'll have to expand your IF condition.

Note: You'll have to decide if you want either `<` or `<=` below, as I don't know your spec.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
my $start = "25823";
my $end = "35841";

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my ($feat, $datastart, $dataend) = split "\t";
    if (grep {$start < $_ && $_ < $end} ($datastart, $dataend) ) {
        print "$_\n"
    }
}

__DATA__
A   23594   24158 
W   25646   25978
X   26189   26770
Y   31694   33466
Z   34568   36125
B   37516   38912
```

Outputs:

```
W   25646   25978
X   26189   26770
Y   31694   33466
Z   34568   36125
```